# Could not resolve com.android.support:design:26.1.0

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-design-library, android-snackbar, android-support-design

I have been having this problem for quite a while, that my `com.android.support:design:26.1.0` fails me and I have no clue what to change anymore.

**These are my files for module gradle.**

> **Build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0'
//    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> **The project gradle file**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter({ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" })
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter({ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" })
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support:design:26.1.0.
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency
>   for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support:design:26.1.0.
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency
>   for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support:design:26.1.0.
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency
>   for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support:design:26.1.0.
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency
>   for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support:design:26.1.0.

And only the 'Snackbar' function does not work but rest of it seems fine.

When I change the design to 25.1.0 version instead, it works but it clashes with other 26.1.0 ones so it's not recommended by the Android Studio. Anyone..?

I have tried putting the

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

instead of implement, it does not work. When I tried to change the whole thing to either 25.4.0 or any other 25 version, a lot of other things doesnt compile as well. I have unchecked the Offline work, tried removing / adding maven directory, un-commenting a few more of dependencies, changing all to compile instead of implement but just gives me more errors.

Yes I have updated all my SDKs to the newest but I have a feeling that Gradle just cannot download certain dependencies from the websites that's why I cannot download any more of the other dependencies. (Although my off-line work is unchecked)

Also, whatever that are uncommented in the code above, it means I have tried inputting those lines but it did not solve the issue or rather created more issues.

Comment: Please update the SDK tools

Comment: @akshay SDK tools are the latest version but I still have the same problem. Just checked it again too.

Comment: @akshay so do you know of any other thing that I could possibly try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem that I realized in the end was that when I was setting up the android proxy, I have only set up 1 proxy which was for HTTP and did not realize that HTTPS proxy was not set up.

So after fixing that issue by setting HTTPS proxy, there was no more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way i found it please try the below

```
Go to File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once ,instead of implementing compile the design support gradle code

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

and remove this

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Comment: As you could have probably seen, I have un-commented the
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0' 
as it was not working as well. I should have written down more clearly what I have done so far